# React nested component

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm new in react and recently i see the jsx syntax like below :

```
function Compound(){
  return(
    <div></div>
  );
}

function NestCompound(){
  return(
    <Compound>
      <h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>
    </Compound>
  );
}
const div_root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
div_root.render(<NestCompound/>);
```

what below code mean :

```
 <Compound>
      <h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>
 </Compound>
```

does is this same like :

```
<div> 
  <h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: If you run the code, you'll see that it's in fact *not* the same.

Answer (score 0):

When we wrap anything inside any component call its treated as a children.
For example, when you call  **Component** like

```
 <Compound>
      <h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>
 </Compound>
```

The content inside this will be **children**. To use this you should extract this inside the component like given below and use it inside div

```
function Compound(props){
  const {children} = props;
  return(
    <div>{children}</div>
  );
}
```

As you didn't use the {children} so your code

```
 <Compound>
      <h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>
 </Compound>
```

will be equivalent to

```
<div> 
</div>
```